# Mocked java class in spock test is not being executed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock

I'm trying to use spock framework for unit testing some java class. The structure looks like this:

- `com.myorg.requests` (Class name: `RequestProcessor`)
- `com.myorg.query` (Class name: `DatabaseQuery`)

The first class looks something like this:

```
public class RequestProcessor {

   private String request;

   public RequestProcessor(String aRequest) {
      this.request = request;
   }

   public String processRequest() {
       String response ;
       //do something here

       try {
           if(condition meets) {
              response = executeRequest();
           }
       } catch ( various exceptions... ) {
           System.out.println("something went wrong...");
       }
   }

   private String executeRequest() throws <<exceptions thrown by DatabaseQuery>> {
       //do something here
       DatabaseQuery queryResult = new DatabaseQuery(request)
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a Spock test for this `RequestProcessor` class which has a dependency on `DatabaseQuery`. I'm thinking of mocking `DatabaseQuery` class in order to simply test the `RequestProcessor` class in isolation.

The `RequestProcessor`'s `processRequest()` method is being called, which relies on another private method. That method will use `DatabaseQuery` to get the actual query result. This is what my Spock test looks like:

```
class RequestProcessorSpec extends Specification {

    //Class to be tested
    RequestProcessor requestProcessor

    //Dependencies
    DatabaseQuery dbquery

    def "Given a valid request, dbquery's executeQuery method is called" () {
        given: "a valid request"
            def queryRequest = '{"info1":"value1","info2":"value2","query":"select * from users"}'

        and: "mock the DBQuery class"
            dbquery = Mock(DatabaseQuery)

        and: "create a new request"
            requestProcessor = new RequestProcessor(queryRequest)

        when: "the request is processed"
            requestHandler.processRequest()

        then: "dbquery executeQuery method is called"
            1 * dbquery.executeQuery(_ as String)
    }
 }
```

This isn't exactly working for me. I'm getting an error:

- Too few invocations
- Unmatched invocations

When I run the test with `gradlew test --info` for more results, I see a log printed on the console that is captured by try-catch statement in `processRequest` method.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problems in the sample code

First of all, your sample code does not work, even if I simplify it and create my own dummy `DatabaseQuery` class because you have at least three errors here:

- In the constructor you have `this.request = request` (self-assignment), but it should be `this.request = aRequest;`.
- In the test you have `requestHandler.processRequest()`, but is should be `requestProcessor.processRequest()`.
- Method `executeRequest()` does not return a `String` as specified. So I can only speculate that in reality it calls another method upon `DatabaseQuery` so as to convert the query result into a `String`.

#### Why is the mock not working?

Having gotten that out of the way, let's see what is really fundamentally wrong with your test.

> What am I doing wrong here?

To assume that the mock in your local variable is somehow effective in the other local variable in your application code. In order for a mock to be used you need to inject it into the class under test. But like so many developers, you did not design for decoupling and testability via dependency injection but you are creating your dependency - in this case the `DatabaseQuery` object - internally.

#### What else is wrong with the test?

I think your test just suffers from over-specification. Why would you want to check if a specific method in another class is called from a private method (indirectly, at that)? You do not directly test private methods but cover their code by calling public methods, and your test already does that.

If you want to cover your `catch` blocks, just make sure that your request causes the right exceptions. Maybe you need to mock the database connection for that and make sure it returns the expected results to the `DatabaseQuery`. I do not see enough of your code in order to say exactly.

#### Technical solution for the original problem

Now let's assume you absolutely want to check this interaction, no matter what I have said before. What you need to do depends on the situation (which you do not show in your code):

In any case you need to make the `DatabaseQuery` injectable. You can just add a member and another setter to your class.

Now you have a fork in the road depending on where the the interaction `dbquery.executeQuery(_ as String)` is made (called) from:

1. If the method is called from outside `DatabaseQuery`, you can inject a normal `Mock`.
2. If the method is called from inside `DatabaseQuery`, you need to inject a `Spy` because a mock would not call other internal methods like the original object because - well, it is just a mock.

**Case 1: `executeQuery(String)` is called from outside**

```java
package de.scrum_master.query;

public class DatabaseQuery {
  private String request;

  public DatabaseQuery(String request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  public String executeQuery(String request) {
    return request.toUpperCase();
  }

  public String getResult() {
    return executeQuery(request);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.requests;

import de.scrum_master.query.DatabaseQuery;

public class RequestProcessor {
  private String request;
  private DatabaseQuery databaseQuery;

  public RequestProcessor(String aRequest) {
    this.request = aRequest;
    databaseQuery = new DatabaseQuery(request);
  }

  public String processRequest() {
    return executeRequest();
  }

  private String executeRequest() {
    return databaseQuery.executeQuery(request);
    //return databaseQuery.getResult();
  }

  public void setDatabaseQuery(DatabaseQuery databaseQuery) {
    this.databaseQuery = databaseQuery;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.requests

import de.scrum_master.query.DatabaseQuery
import spock.lang.Specification

class RequestProcessorTest extends Specification {
  //Class to be tested
  RequestProcessor requestProcessor

  //Dependencies
  DatabaseQuery dbquery

  def "Given a valid request, dbquery's executeQuery method is called" () {
    given: "a valid request"
    def queryRequest = '{"info1":"value1","info2":"value2","query":"select * from users"}'

    and: "mock the DBQuery class"
    dbquery = Mock(DatabaseQuery)
    //dbquery = Spy(DatabaseQuery, constructorArgs: [queryRequest])

    and: "create a new request"
    requestProcessor = new RequestProcessor(queryRequest)
    requestProcessor.databaseQuery = dbquery

    when: "the request is processed"
    requestProcessor.processRequest()

    then: "dbquery executeQuery method is called"
    1 * dbquery.executeQuery(_ as String)
  }
}
```

Now the test works including the interaction check.

**Case 2: `executeQuery(String)` is called internally from its own class**

Did you see the two commented-out lines in `RequestProcessor` and `RequestProcessorTest`? Just use them and comment out the other two instead like this:

```java
  private String executeRequest() {
    //return databaseQuery.executeQuery(request);
    return databaseQuery.getResult();
  }
```

```java
    and: "mock the DBQuery class"
    //dbquery = Mock(DatabaseQuery)
    dbquery = Spy(DatabaseQuery, constructorArgs: [queryRequest])
```

The test still works including the interaction check.

Of course I had to fake a few things and fill in the missing puzzle tiles you did not provide, but this is basically how it works.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to and the explanations. As you can tell, I didn't copy the full code here. That's why there were some errors after I posted the example. I'll need to take some time to go through your explanation and examples. Just writing to say thanks!!

Comment: Welcome. It should not take much time because my sample code is a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including package and class names, test and application sample code. Just copy, paste and run.

Comment: What would be proper way to doing this? RequestProcessor class only has 1 public method. A successful call of that method depends on a private method on the same class, which instantiates another class (DatabaseQuery). For negative test scenario, I think I can check if the public method call (processRequest) ran into any exception but, how can I test happy path properly that is dependent on a private method? Also, should I really make "databaseQuery" a global variable even though it's only used by 1 particular private method?

Comment: I do not understand your questions. I did not make the database query a **"global variable"** as you call it. It is a **private member** variable. I merely added an option to inject it. Have you ever read about dependency injection as a design pattern? If you do not like the setter, you can also use constructor injection. Anyway, I think I already answered the initial question, as demonstrated by my code. I would hope you accept and upvote it and create a new question if you have any new problems. Because for the "proper way of doing this" I do need more information, not just snippets.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation. It was very helpful. I need to re-evaluate the current implementation.